# Setting HTML table borders to combine tables to appear to look like one table (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

This long question can be combined into one simple sentence: **How do I set a border of a table selectively (bottom or top) without impacting its tr or td elements?** I thought it would be as simple as changing the border of any element. I was wrong.

**The rest of the question explains where I need this and what I have tried so far.**

Here is a simplified description of the HTML markup:
There are three divs with three tables. I want to make them look as a single table. The three divs are required for reasons not relevant here.

If I use the following:

```js
$('#tbl1').css('border-bottom', 'none');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
                <table id="tbl1" border="1" style="width:400px;" >
                     <thead>
                             <tr>
                                     <td>Head Row 1, cell 1</td>
                                     <td>Head Row 1, cell 2</td>
                                     <td>Head Row 1, cell 3</td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                     <td>Head Row 2, cell 1</td>
                                     <td>Head Row 2, cell 2</td>
                                     <td>Head Row 2, cell 3</td>
                             </tr>
                     </thead>
             </table>
             </div>
    
             <div id="div2" >
             <table id="tbl2" style="width:400px;" border="1">
                     <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                     <td>Row 1, cell 1</td>
                                     <td>Row 1, cell 2</td>
                                     <td>Row 1, cell 3</td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                     <td>Row 1, cell 1</td>
                                     <td>Row 1, cell 2</td>
                                     <td>Row 1, cell 3</td>
                             </tr>
                     </tbody>
             </table>
             </div>
    
             <div id="div3" >
             <table id="tbl3" border="1" style="width:400px;">
             <tfoot>
                             <tr>
                                     <td>Foot Row 1, cell 1</td>
                                     <td>Foot Row 1, cell 2</td>
                                     <td>Foot Row 1, cell 3</td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                     <td>Foot Row 2, cell 1</td>
                                     <td>Foot Row 2, cell 2</td>
                                     <td>Foot Row 2, cell 3</td>
                             </tr>
             </tfoot>
             </table>
       </div>
```

it takes the lower border of all cells in the first table and not just the table's bottom-border. If I use:

```js
 $('#tbl1' + ' tr:last-child').css('border-bottom', 'none')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
                <table id="tbl1" border="1" style="width:400px;" >
                     <thead>
                             <tr>
                                     <td>Head Row 1, cell 1</td>
                                     <td>Head Row 1, cell 2</td>
                                     <td>Head Row 1, cell 3</td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                     <td>Head Row 2, cell 1</td>
                                     <td>Head Row 2, cell 2</td>
                                     <td>Head Row 2, cell 3</td>
                             </tr>
                     </thead>
             </table>
             </div>
    
             <div id="div2" >
             <table id="tbl2" style="width:400px;" border="1">
                     <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                     <td>Row 1, cell 1</td>
                                     <td>Row 1, cell 2</td>
                                     <td>Row 1, cell 3</td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                     <td>Row 1, cell 1</td>
                                     <td>Row 1, cell 2</td>
                                     <td>Row 1, cell 3</td>
                             </tr>
                     </tbody>
             </table>
             </div>
    
             <div id="div3" >
             <table id="tbl3" border="1" style="width:400px;">
             <tfoot>
                             <tr>
                                     <td>Foot Row 1, cell 1</td>
                                     <td>Foot Row 1, cell 2</td>
                                     <td>Foot Row 1, cell 3</td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                                     <td>Foot Row 2, cell 1</td>
                                     <td>Foot Row 2, cell 2</td>
                                     <td>Foot Row 2, cell 3</td>
                             </tr>
             </tfoot>
             </table>
       </div>
```

it does take the bottom border of the last row of the first table but retains the bottom-border of the table itself.

The above problems, of course, are repeated for handling the situation for the lowest two tables.

My goal is to have all traces of borders joining the tables be removed so that I can assign one thick or any other type of border to one table as the table-separator. So, to clarify further:

The bottom border of the first table and the top border of the second table as well as the corresponding borders of the tr and tds of the corresponding rows must be removed.

The top border of third table and the bottom border of the second table as well as the corresponding border of the tr and tds of the corresponding rows must be removed.

After this I can set any border I want to act as a table separator.

The middle table will be scrollable so I will be placing a new bottom border on the top table and a new top-border on the bottom border.

The solution must be as generic as possible to accommodate any possible table layout but with the restriction that a row is a tr and that each table will have at least one tr.

Comment: just u want to display all the tables inside a single box ?

Comment: @AmareshSM  I have figured everything out so far. The issue is how to set border-bottom or border-top on a table without impacting inner rows/cells/columns. It is a simple question really but because questions get rejected if code is not provided, I have provided some code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to unborder middle table, not tr or td.

Also add negative margin to middle div

```css
table#tbl1 {
border-bottom:none;
}
table#tbl2 {
border-top:none;
border-bottom:none;

}
table#tbl3 {
border-top:none;
}
#div2 {
margin:-2px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <table id="tbl1" border="1" style="width:400px;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Head Row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td>Head Row 1, cell 2</td>
        <td>Head Row 1, cell 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Head Row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td>Head Row 2, cell 2</td>
        <td>Head Row 2, cell 3</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="div2">
  <table id="tbl2" style="width:400px;" border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 1, cell 2</td>
        <td>Row 1, cell 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td>Row 1, cell 2</td>
        <td>Row 1, cell 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="div3">
  <table id="tbl3" border="1" style="width:400px;">
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>Foot Row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td>Foot Row 1, cell 2</td>
        <td>Foot Row 1, cell 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Foot Row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td>Foot Row 2, cell 2</td>
        <td>Foot Row 2, cell 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `border-collapse` to merge the borders, then using the `:not` selector, choose all tables except the one in the last DIV, to remove their bottom borders (in css, not js):

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

div:not(:last-child) table {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EqNMNm

Comment: border-collapse changes the look of the table rows and I do not have that choice. At this time, my simple question is how to set border-bottom or border-top of a table without impacting inner rows/cells/columns. $(selector).css('border-bottom', 'none') does not work on table as it also removes the bottom border of all footer rows not just the table.

Comment: In that case, since `th` and `td` border styles are inherited, you will have to overwrite the changes specifically for each of the changes you make:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KONYZy